# c++ decode CCITT encoded images in pdfs

Tags: c++, pdf, imagemagick, decode, magick++

I'm trying to extract all images out of PDF files in C++. I'm stuck in decoding CCITT encoded images.

Does anyone know an opensourced code for this?

I use the ImageMagick Magick++ Library, is it possible to do the decoding with this library, too?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CCITT is one of the encodings TIFF supports, though in a PDF file the CCITT images are probably raw data.

You can convert a raw CCITT image into a Tiff image using [Fax2Tiff](http://www.libtiff.org/man/fax2tiff.1.html).  It should be easy enough to work with the image once it is encoded as a Tiff.

Fax2Tiff is part of LibTiff.  See [LibTiff Source](http://www.libtiff.org/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Fax2Tiff seems not to be a library, it is a tool. I need to do the conversion in the program.

Comment: @FlashFan: While Fax2Tiff *is* a tool, it's also open source.  Find the source code for it within LibTiff and adjust it as needed for your purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can append a header on it and treat it as a tiff file.

Comment: Basically, that is what my answer is suggesting.

Comment: How would "adding a header" work with libtiff. Have you some sample c++ code?